# Given a matrix (i.e. an array of arrays), find its submatrix obtained by deleting the specified rows and columns

Tags: java

I am trying to solve this coding challenge on CodeSignal.

```
Example

    For matrix = [[1, 0, 0, 2], 
              [0, 5, 0, 1], 
              [0, 0, 3, 5]]
    rowsToDelete = [1], and columnsToDelete = [0, 2], 
the output should be[[0, 2],[0, 5]]
```

This is my code:

```
    int[][] constructSubmatrix(int[][] matrix, int[] rowsToDelete, int[] columnsToDelete) {
        int numRows = matrix.length;
        int numCols = matrix[0].length;
        int numRowsToDelete = rowsToDelete.length;
        int numColsToDelete = columnsToDelete.length;
        int[][] newMatrix = new int[numRows-numRowsToDelete][numCols-numColsToDelete];
        int i1=0; 
        for(int i=0; (i<numRows) && (Arrays.binarySearch(rowsToDelete,i)<0); i++) {
            int j1=0;
            for(int j=0; (j<numCols) && (Arrays.binarySearch(columnsToDelete,j)<0); j++) {
                newMatrix[i1][j1]=matrix[i][j];
                j1++;
            }
            i1++;
        }
        return newMatrix;
    }
```

Am I doing anything explicily wrong?

But I am gettign the output:

```
[[0,0], 
 [0,0]]
```

I believe it is because Arrays.binarySearch always returns a match. Am I understanding the function wrong?

Comment: What is your thinking behind `Arrays.binarySearch(rowsToDelete,i)<0` in both `for` loops?

Comment: if the key is found in any of the arrays, those rows or columns which the keys signify shoudl be discarded and not enter for loop for them.

Comment: Do the challenge instructions guarantee that your `_ToDelete` arrays are sorted? Binary search won't work otherwise. Regardless, you're misusing the return value. The inner loop isn't running as it stands.

Comment: From my understanding, the function returns a negative value if the key is not found in the array. Am I wrong? Also, the input arrays are already sorted.

Comment: OK, but as soon as you hit a row that doesn't belong, your totally break the loop. In your example, row 1 must be deleted, so `binarySearch` returns positive and the outer loop breaks entirely.

Comment: Damn, thanks. that was the mistake.

Comment: It's not recommended to remove your non-working code in your post. That invalidates answers and makes the question less useful for future viewers, who have no context for what you were originally asking. I recommend rolling back your latest update. Glad you got it working, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, and `binarySearch` should not impose any significant performance penalties. However, whenever a row is encountered that should not be included in the output (i.e. `binarySearch` returns `>= 0`), either the inner or outer loop will break completely and ignore any subsequent rows or columns that *should* be included in the result array. In your example, when `i == 1`, the `binarySearch` call on `rowsToDelete` returns `>= 0` and breaks the outer loop prematurely.

In terms of edge cases, it's reasonable to write a function that doesn't presume (or impose) the `ToDelete` arrays to be sorted. Furthermore, output would contain additional rows if `ToDelete` arrays contained duplicates.

Taking all of this into consideration, a `Set` is the best data structure for performing fast checks for row/column inclusion and works with parameter arrays that may be unsorted or contain duplicates. Here's a complete, working example:

```
int[][] constructSubmatrix(int[][] matrix, int[] rowsToDelete, int[] columnsToDelete) {
    Set<Integer> rowsDel = new HashSet<>();
    Set<Integer> colsDel = new HashSet<>();

    for (int e : rowsToDelete) { rowsDel.add(e); }
    for (int e : columnsToDelete) { colsDel.add(e); }

    int[][] newMatrix = new int[matrix.length-rowsDel.size()]
                               [matrix[0].length-colsDel.size()];

    for (int i = 0, newI = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        if (!rowsDel.contains(i)) {
            for (int j = 0, newJ = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
                if (!colsDel.contains(j)) {
                    newMatrix[newI][newJ++] = matrix[i][j];
                }
            }

            newI++;
        }
    }

    return newMatrix;
}
```

[Try it!](https://repl.it/repls/PlushSphericalEntropy)